# How to separate Business logic and metrics log?

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns

In lots of Applications, we need to log statistics metrics, such as hist, guage and so on. This will pollute the business logic. For example:

```
boolean buy(int id) {
  metrics.increament(); // for qps maybe.. 
  int remain = checkRemain();
  metrics.hist(remain); // log remain amount..
  if (remain > 0)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}
```

which, I hope, I can only write down the biz logic, such as:

```
boolean buy(int id) {
  int remain = checkRemain();
  if (remain > 0)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}
```

But also I can get the metrics.

My question is: what's the best practice to separate Business logic and metrics log?

I know Aspect--Oriented Programming may solve this, do I have any other choice?

Comment: Why don't you want to choose AOP?

Comment: Why are you concerned with updating metrics within the business logic?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use AOP you can implement an observer

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

Define an Observer interface

```
public interface Observer {
    void buyed(int id, int remain);
}
```

Then use in business logic class:

```
 private List<Observer> observers = new ArrayList<>();
 public void addObserver(Observer observer) {
    this.observers.add(observer);
 }

 boolean buy(int id){    
    int remain = checkRemain();
    for (Observer observer : this.observers) {
        observer.buyed(id, remain);
    }
    if (remain > 0){  
      return true;
    } else
     return false;
}
```

Metrics class implements observer interface

```
class Metrics implements Observer {
   void buyed(int id, int remain){
       metrics.increment();
       metrics.hist(remain); 
   }
....
```